# In gradient checking, do we add/subtract epsilon (a tiny value) to both theta and constant parameter b?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I've been doing Andrew Ng's DeepLearning AI course (course 2).

For the exercise in gradient checking, he implements a function converting a dictionary containing all of the weights (W) and constants (b) into a single, one-hot encoded vector (of dimensions 47 x 1).

The starter code then iterates through this vector, adding epsilon to each entry in the vector.

Does gradient checking generally include adding epsilon/subtracting to the constant as well? Or is it simply for convenience, as constants play a relatively small role in the overall calculation of the cost function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it regardless, even for constants. The reason is simple: being constants, you know their gradient is zero, so you still want to check you "compute" it correctly. You can see it as an additional safety net

Comment: I don't get it, if the gradient is zero, shouldnt it be pointless? Or do you mean the safety net as in you screwed up your backprop, in which case the gradient check will compare your screwed up value to two actual values of b that give a gradient of zero?

Comment: @A.Xu you are right and that's what I meant :) you know it _should_ be zero, so you simply make sure your code _does_ return 0

Comment: Ah okay now that makes more sense! Thanks!